# Do multiple reference variables pointing to the same object each take up the same memory footprint as the object

Tags: java, object, reference-type

Say for example I have four classes A, B, C and D; where D's constructor takes A, B and C as parameters. If I have the following implementation:

```
public static main(String[] args) {
  A = new A();
  B = new B();
  C = new C();
  D = new D(A, B, C);
}
```

And the instance variables for D are:

```
  private A objA;
  private B objB;
  private C objC;
```

Will, for instance, the "value" of A (new A()) be copied to objA after D's instantiation?

Comment: Related: [Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java only has references and primitive types. When you assign a reference to a variable it always takes the same amount if memory regardless of what object it references. Typically a reference is 4 bytes but can be 8 bytes for large heaps over 32 GB in size.

> Will, for instance, the "value" of A (new A()) be copied to objA after D's instantiation?

In this case, the value of `A` is a reference to an object and that reference is copied. The object referenced isn't touched (neither copied or read)

Comment: Great answer. I'm assuming you meant to say "for large heaps over 32GB in size" on the last sentence of the first paragraph am I right?

Comment: @Garikai yes, I was typing on my phone.